# How to install vips command line utility in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

From the vips's website I can only find this information about installing the package `libvips`. In Ubuntu 16.04 it will automatically switch to libvips42. It installs mainly the `.so` files:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvips-cpp.so.42.3.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvipsCC.so.42.3.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvips.so.42.3.2
```

However I actually want to install is the utility commands such as `vipsthumbnails`. What is the right package for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find any Ubuntu package or the contents of any Ubuntu package using https://packages.ubuntu.com.  I found that `vipsthumbnail` is provided by `libvips-tools` by using [the site's file search.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=vipsthumbnail&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any)

For any package in the Ubuntu repository, there should be a handy link on the packages site that will show you the files included in any particular package.